# Check, Un check check box while selecting parent and child check box node using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Basically I have a 2 level setup:

```
Parent 
   Child
     Sub Child
       Sub Sub child
Parent1
    Child 1
      Sub Child 1
      etc..
```

- If the parent is checked/unchecked, then its children and
  sub child should all be not disturbed that means  (unchecked ).
- If the child or subchild is checked/unchecked, its parent should be
  checked
- If the children or subchild are unchecked, then its parent should be unchecked .

My overall focus will be if the child or subchild are checked then its parent node should be checked. if we are trying to check child but not parent means we can't allow to uncheck the parent node while checked its child. but we can check uncheck the parent while not check the child or subchild.

My Code :

```
jQuery('li :checkbox').change(function() {
            var $parent = $(this).parents().eq(2);
            $parent.children('li :checkbox').prop('checked', $parent.find('li :checkbox:checked').size() > 0).change();
        });
```

HTML :

```
<ul id="treeList">
   <li>
   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
   Application Manager
    <ul>
       <li>
           <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
           Application Manager Panel
       </li>
       <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
            Client Role
             <ul>
               <li>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
                   Client Task 1
                </li>
                <li>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
                    Client Task 2
                </li>

                 </ul>
              </li>

          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
            Client Role
             <ul>
               <li>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
                   Client Task 1
                </li>
                <li>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="selectedRole">
                    Client Task 2
                </li>


           </ul>
       </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kmPK7/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny In this Example while i checked the child node the parent node get checked, but while i uncheck the selected child parent node , then that child node should be unchecked ..but this example is showing checked...this problem only i'm, currently facing in my code too..can you give some suggestion on this

Comment: "If the child or subchild is checked/unchecked, its parent should be checked" and "If the children or subchild are unchecked, then its parent should be unchecked"?

Comment: @coma absolutely correct...please one more thing ..if separately the parent is checked then the child of the parent should not checked/unchecked..

Comment: I find the solution of my question : http://jsfiddle.net/aarukarthiga/P7s2A/